# Java File object makes entry to inode?

Tags: java, linux, file, recursion

In my program I am traversing a directory and its subdirectories like this

```
public void foo(File file){    
File filelist[] = file.listFiles();
    for(File f: filelist){
        if(f.isDirectory()) foo(f);
        fun(f);
    }
}
```

I am getting too many open files error. I was wondering if File object makes an entry to a free inode or something else is wrong.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 64 bit edition.
I have 5 million files in several subdirectories.
I have given 6GB ram to this process (-Xmx6g).

EDIT: Yes the problem was in fun() method, where I was using

```
doc.writeTo(new FileWriter(file))
```

Generelly GC takes care of it, but I had large number of files so it was too late for GC.

Comment: so the error is in `f.isDirectory()`? or in `fun(f)`? can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: In fun(f), where I am creating another file for writing.

Comment: append what `fun(f)` does and try to append the stacktrace too

Comment: You have not said what you do in `fun(f)`, but the most probably, you open a file, do something with it, and then you forget to close it, which leads to a huge recursive list of files open and not closed.  Right?  Could be something like this?

Comment: 'Generelly GC takes care of it': No. This is poor practice. GC isn't intended to take care of closing files for you. If you're consuming resources you should release them yourself, as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a `File` object doesn't modify or hold inodes; it's really just a representation of a path on the filesystem. Most likely, `fun(f)` is opening files and never closing them, and the OS limits how many files can be open simultaneously. The file-descriptor limit has nothing to do with the amount of memory or disk space is in use.